# only open output file if input file isn't empty

Tags: perl

I have a script in which I ask the user if he wants to input a file. If he does this & the file isn't empty than I want to use this file and open an outputfile for results. I want to repeat this question 3 times so that the user can import maximal 3 files. This is how my script looks like:

```
(12) my $genes1;
(13) my $genes2;
(14) my $genes3;

(16) if (prompt_yn("Do you want to import a genelist for filtering?")){
(17)      my $genelist1 = prompt("Give the name of the first genelist file:\n");
(18)      print "genelist1 = \"$genelist1\"\n";
(19)      open($genes1,'<',$genelist1) or die "Could not open file $genelist1 $!";
(20)      if (prompt_yn("Do you want to import another gene list file?")){
(21)           my $genelist2 = prompt("Give the name of the second genelist file:\n");
(22)           print "genelist2 = \"$genelist2\"\n";
(23)           open($genes2,'<',$genelist2) or die "Could not open file $genelist2 $!";
(24)           if (prompt_yn("Do you want to import another gene list file?")){
(25)                 my $genelist3 = prompt("Give the name of the third genelist file:\n");
(26)                 print "genelist3 = \"$genelist3\"\n";
(27)                 open($genes3,'<',$genelist3) or die "Could not open file $genelist3 $!";
(28)           }
(29)      }
(30) }
(32) print "genes1 = \"$genes1\"\n";
(33) print "genes2 = \"$genes2\"\n";
(34) print "genes3 = \"$genes3\"\n";
(45) my $genelist1filter;
(46) my $genelist1restfilter;
(47) my $genelist2filter;
(48) my $genelist2restfilter;
(49) my $genelist3filter;
(50) my $genelist3restfilter;
(51) printf "At line %d\n", __LINE__;
(52) print "genes1 is ", defined $genes1 ? "defined\n" : "not defined\n";
(53) print "genes2 is ", defined $genes2 ? "defined\n" : "not defined\n";
(54) print "genes3 is ", defined $genes3 ? "defined\n" : "not defined\n";
(56) if (-e $genes1 && -s $genes1){
(57)    printf "At line %d\n", __LINE__;
(58)    open($genelist1filter, '+>', "genelist1_missense_nonsense_frameshift_inframe_startloss_stoploss.txt") || die "Can't write new file: $!"; printf "At line %d\n", __LINE__;
(59)    #first output file
(60)    open($genelist1restfilter, '+>', "notingenelist_missense_nonsense_frameshift_inframe_startloss_stoploss.txt") || die "Can't write new file: $!"; #second output file
(61) } # same for $genes2 and $genes3
(62) printf "At line %d\n", __LINE__;

# line56 to 62 is repeated for $genes2(lines63-69) and for $genes3(lines70-77)

(183)# genelist2 filtering 
     my %hash2=();
     while(<$genes2>){
     chomp;
     #next unless -z $_;
     my $keyfield = $_;
     $hash2{$keyfield}++;
(190) }

(201)# genelist3 filtering 
     my %hash3=();
     while(<$genes3>){
     chomp;
     #next unless -z $_;
     my $keyfield = $_;
     $hash3{$keyfield}++;
(208) }
```

Now when I test this script and let the user input 1 genelist (so 'yes' to first question & providing a name) & then answering 'no' to second question), I get the message that there is use of an unitialized value in -e near `$genes2` and `$genes3`. I suppose there is something wrong with the `-e` and `-s` to check if the file exists and isn't empty? Could someone comment on this?

This is how the output looks like (script based on the edits from AndrianHHH)

```
Do you want to import a genelist for filtering? (Y/N): y
Give the name of the first genelist file:
genelist1.txt
genelist1 = "genelist1.txt"
Do you want to import another gene list file? (Y/N): n
genes1 = "GLOB(0x134c568)"
Use of uninitialized value $genes2 in concatenation (.) or string at filtering.pl line 33, <STDIN> line 3.
genes2 = ""
Use of uninitialized value $genes3 in concatenation (.) or string at filtering.pl line 34, <STDIN> line 3.
genes3 = ""
At line 51 
genes1 is defined
genes2 is not defined
genes3 is not defined
At line 57
At line 58
At line 62
Use of uninitialized value $genes2 in -e at filtering.pl line 63, <STDIN> at line 3                                                                                                       At line 69
Use of uninitialized value $genes3 in -e at filtering.pl line 70, <STDIN> line 3.
At line 77
Use of uninitialized value $genes2 in <HANDLE> at filtering.pl line 185.
readline() on unopened filehandle at filtering.pl line 185.
Use of uninitialized value $genes3 in <HANDLE> at filtering.pl line 203.
readline() on unopened filehandle at filtering.pl line 203.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting `if (-e -s $genes1){` as `if (-e $genes1 && -s $genes1){`.

The `-e` and `-s` file tests returns 1 for true and '' for false, or the undefined value if the file doesn't exist. The original code appeared to be equivalent to (eg) `my $a=1; my $b=1; if($a $b) {` which is probably not what was intended. Additionally, omitting an argument to `-e` or -`s` make it work on `$_`. Hence suggesting the rewrite in the top line of this answer.

With the change made as above it would appear that `$genes1` is undefined. But that looks unlikely given the `open ... or die ...` above.

I would run the program in the Perl debugger, or alternatively, add a statement such as this just before the tests:

```
print "genes1 is ", defined $genes1 ? "defined\n" : "not defined\n";
```

Update

The code you provided seems to work fine with a Perl where `perl -v` reports **This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread**. As the code in the question is not complete I added the prompt code written by **amon** in the answer to your question [prompting multiple questions to user (yes/no & file name input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103501/prompting-multiple-questions-to-user-yes-no-file-name-input) . I also added some print statements to show the flow through the code. Finally, I changed the indentation of the first set of nested `if` statement to show the structure a little more clearly.

Please check that the code in the question is a true copy of the code you are running. Please also check that the prompt code you are using does not modify the `$genes1` variable.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($genes1, $genes2, $genes3);

if (prompt_yn("Do you want to import a genelist for filtering?")){ #prompt_yn is a subroutine which I already tested & it worked
    my $genelist1 = prompt("Give the name of the first genelist file:\n");
    print "genelist1 = \"$genelist1\"\n";
    open($genes1,'<',$genelist1) or die "Could not open file $genelist1 $!";
    if (prompt_yn("Do you want to import another gene list file?")){
        my $genelist2 = prompt("Give the name of the second genelist file:\n");
        print "genelist2 = \"$genelist2\"\n";
        open($genes2,'<',$genelist2) or die "Could not open file $genelist2 $!";
        if (prompt_yn("Do you want to import another gene list file?")){
            my $genelist3 = prompt("Give the name of the third genelist file:\n");
            print "genelist2 = \"$genelist3\"\n";
            open($genes3,'<',$genelist3) or die "Could not open file $genelist3 $!";
        }
    }
}

print "genes1 = \"$genes1\"\n";
print "genes2 = \"$genes2\"\n";
print "genes2 = \"$genes3\"\n";


my ($genelist1filter, $genelist1restfilter, $genelist2filter, $genelist2restfilter, $genelist3filter, $genelist3restfilter) ;

printf "At line %d\n", __LINE__;
print "genes1 is ", defined $genes1 ? "defined\n" : "not defined\n";

if (-e  $genes1 && -s $genes1){
    printf "At line %d\n", __LINE__;
    open($genelist1filter, '+>', "genelist1_missense_nonsense_frameshift_inframe_startloss_stoploss.txt") || die "Can't write new file: $!"; printf "At line %d\n", __LINE__;
    #first output file
    open($genelist1restfilter, '+>', "notingenelist_missense_nonsense_frameshift_inframe_startloss_stoploss.txt") || die "Can't write new file: $!"; #second output file
} # same for $genes2 and $genes3

printf "At line %d\n", __LINE__;


sub prompt {
    my ($query) = @_; # take a prompt string as argument
    local $| = 1; # activate autoflush to immediately show the prompt
    print $query;
    chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>);
    return $answer;
}


sub prompt_yn {
    my ($query) = @_;
    my $answer = prompt("$query (Y/N): ");
    return lc($answer) eq 'y';
}
```

**Another update:**

The output shown in the revision to the question shows what is happening. The `-e` and -`s` applied to `$genes1` work fine. The problem is when hey are applied to `$genes2` and `$genes3` when no files are provided. The prints from lines 33 and 34 are shown in the output just above the text `At line 51` and they confirm that `$genes2` and `$genes3` are not defined. They are assigned values by the `open(...)` calls in lines 23 and 27, otherwise they are left with the undefined values they get when declared at lines 13 and 14.

In the file test `-e $genes1`, the value `$genes1` contains a handle to an open file and hence the test is valid. No second or third file is wanted, so the `open`s are not performed for `$genes2` and `$genes3`, so they have undefined values.

The tests should probably be changed to be:

```
if ( defined $genes1 && -s $genes1){
if ( defined $genes2 && -s $genes2){
```

and

```
if ( defined $genes3 && -s $genes3){
```

Comment: still get the same message when changing this

Comment: when adding the statement, it prints: "genes1 is defined". After that I get the same message as before

Comment: I'm using perl 5 version 14 subversion 2. This is indeed my code. Could I send you the output?

Comment: Please add the output by editing your question. If it includes line numbers then please also copy the source line reported plus a few immediately above and below and indicate line numbers.

Comment: I added the output and the script with line indications

Comment: @user1987607 Explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving the -e and -s to separate `if` blocks - check if the file exists in the first block and add the file size check within this block. Example,

```
# check for existence
if (-e $genes1)
{
    # check size only if file exists
    if (-s $genes1)
    {
        # processing takes place here
    }
}
```

Comment: Perlfun (in ActivePerl v5.16.3) states of the file test operators "This unary operator takes one argument, either a filename, a filehandle, or a dirhandle, and tests the associated file to see if something is true about it". So file handles should work OK.

Comment: @JTG still get the same message when changing this